# How to count a value in a range using array formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I want to count the number of `No` in theses ranges `F:R`,`BC:BN`,`CX:DI` with array formula so if any one submit a new response containing `No` in these ranges it counts them

I tried using this formula

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(E:E)=1,"NC",IF(LEN(E:E), IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(COUNTIFS(OR(DV:EG="No",BW:CH="No",U:AG="No"))),, 999^99)), "♦"))="♦", 1, 0), )))`

but it didn't work,  I also tried this formula: 
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"NC",IF(LEN(A:A)=0,IFERROR(1/0),COUNTIFS(F:R,"No")+COUNTIFS(BC:BN,"No")+COUNTIFS(CX:DI,"No"))))`
But it counted all the value in the whole range

I need it to count the No row by row so at the end of every row under `NC` it shows the number of the No in these ranges `F:R`,`BC:BN`,`CX:DI`

Here is a spread sheet containing the data 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SksZv0h82j5oEZBj2AN5anDFr80AYNR5ettSwkpUKys/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"NC"; IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 MMULT(IFERROR(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT({F2:R,BC2:BN,CX2:DI}, "No"))/
               LEN(REGEXEXTRACT({F2:R,BC2:BN,CX2:DI}, "No")), 0),
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:AK1)^0)), )})
```

[image: 0]